# Return end of Promise when every async function in a ForEach loop has been processed [Javascript/Typescript]

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach, promise

I have a ForEach loop in which I call an asynchronous function. With a counter, I can figure out when all the items in my array have been processed, but what I'd like to know, is **how can I return my Promise as resolved when all the items have been processed ?**

```
public doAsyncThingsToArray(array: number[]): Promise<void>
let count: number;
array.forEach((item) => {
    this.doAsynchStuff(item)
})
.then(() => {
    count++;
    if (count == item.length) {
        //Probably something has to be done here
    }
});
```

I want to be able to call my function `doAsyncThingsToArray` like this :

```
    doAsyncThingsToArray(myArray)
    .then(() => {
    //all my array has been processed
    })
```

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

**The code below works**

```
public doAsyncThingsToArray(array: number[]): Promise<void> {

Promise.all(
    array.map((item) => {
        return this.doAsynchStuff(item)
            .then(() => {
                console.log("item processed");
                return Promise.resolve();
            })
    })
)
.then(() => {
  console.log("All item are processed");
  return Promise.resolve();
});
```

Comment: Array `forEach` doesn't return a Promise, aren't you seeing some sort of error? Try using Array `map` with `Promise.all` ... i.e. `Promise.all(array.map(this.doAsynchStuff)).then ...`

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't seem to work yet (see my edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) exist. Do not use `Array#forEach()` when you need a reference to each array item's promise. The body of `doAsyncThingsToArray()` should look like:

```
return Promise.all(array.map((item) => this.doAsyncStuff(item))
```

Where `this.doAsyncStuff()` returns a promise.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It seems to be the way to do it but I'm still encountering some trouble (see my edit).

Comment: @Dogson both of your `.then()` are redundant for actual completion, but they do allow you to add debug logs in the appropriate places for various completion checkpoints.